# SP2010 Migration - A feature with ID 14/5c935448-ed11-4bae-bfff-ef8b307f38ac has already been installed in this farm

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am attempting a migration of SP2010 to SP2013, so far what I have accomplished is below:
1) created a backup of the contentDB from SP2010 and restored it on to SP2013
2) Added all the wsp's exported from SP2010 solution store to SP2013 soltuion store.
3) When I try to deploy a solution I get a error message saying "A feature with ID 14/5c935448-ed11-4bae-bfff-ef8b307f38ac has already been installed in this farm.  Use the force attribute to explicitly re-install the feature."

most of them suggest to turn on force attribute on the feature and then do the deployment in my case I do not have code for the wsp, so unable to recompile them to turn on the force attribute.

Have used the featureadmin for SP2013 it does not find any faulty feature in the farm, it doesnot list any feature with Id 5c935448-ed11-4bae-bfff-ef8b307f38ac.

Executing select fullurl, description from features join AllWebs on 
    (features.webid = AllWebs.id) where featureid = '5c935448-ed11-4bae-bfff-ef8b307f38ac' lists rows of data from db but I can't find the feature folder on 14/15 hive.

Stuck at the moment trying to find a way to get the solutions deployed and perform the db upgrade. Any pointers welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use **Force** parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can define -force with power shell command as well.

Answer (score 0):

Salam Santhosh

I face this problem before , and I resolved by adding the **AlwaysForceInstall="TRUE"** to the feature.xml for the WSP, after that I went to the central admin and I do uninstall and re-install to the WSP, after that you can  activate the feature using STSADM or powershell normally

this is an example of the feature

[image]